# Closed-form solution of a linear programming question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, convex-optimization

Among all the probability matrices
\begin{equation*}
P =
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
p_{00} & p_{01} & \ldots & p_{0,J-1} \\
p_{10} & p_{11} & \ldots & p_{1,J-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots \\
p_{J-1,0} & p_{J-1, 1} & \ldots & p_{J-1,J-1} \\
\end{array} \right)
\quad
(0 \le p_{kl} \le 1, \;\; \sum_{k=0}^{J-1}\sum_{l=0}^{J-1}p_{kl} = 1)
\end{equation*}
with fixed row and column sums
\begin{equation*}
p_{k+} = \sum_{l^\prime=0}^{J-1}p_{kl^\prime},
\quad
p_{+l} = \sum_{k^\prime =0}^{J-1}p_{k^\prime l}
\quad
(k, l = 0, 1, \ldots, J-1),
\end{equation*}
Calculate the closed-form expressions for the minimum and maximum values of
\begin{equation*}
\Delta = \mathop{\sum\sum}_{ k > l}p_{kl}  - \mathop{\sum\sum}_{ k < l}p_{kl}.
\end{equation*}

Some background:

This is an **interesting and challenging** question, in fact, an **active research** problem I am currently pursuing. I can't prove that it indeed has a closed form solution, but I tend to believe so. I have tried very hard and therefore want to solicit any hints or point of directions. On a related note,  I have obtained closed form solutions of the sharp bounds of the following very similar objective functions, namely
\begin{equation*}
\tau = \mathop{\sum\sum}_{ k \ge l}p_{kl},
\quad
\eta = \mathop{\sum\sum}_{ k > l}p_{kl},
\quad
\xi = \mathop{\sum\sum}_{ k = l}p_{kl},
\end{equation*}
which another reason why I believe the solution exists for $\Delta$ as well. For more details see my Ph.D. dissertation at:

dash.harvard.edu/handle/1/23845443

(Update March 31) Let me provide a bit more context. Because of the symmetrical structure of $\Delta,$ we only need to figure out the upper bound. When $J=2$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\Delta = p_{+0} - p_{0+} = p_{1+} - p_{+1} = \min \left( p_{+0} - p_{0+}, p_{1+} - p_{+1}\right),
\end{equation*}
therefore we can identify $\Delta$ from the marginals. When $J=3$, simulations suggest that the sharp upper bound of $\Delta$ is:
\begin{equation*}
\Delta_U = \min \left\{ p_{+0} - p_{0+} + \min\left( p_{2+}, p_{+1}\right),
p_{2+} - p_{+2} + \min\left( p_{1+}, p_{+0}\right) \right\}.
\end{equation*}
However, unfortunately, when $J>3,$ I am no longer able to "guess" the closed-form solutions and therefore I need your help. :)

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level tag in order to make more people see this question.

Comment: An approach would be to first describe the vertices of the polytope, then if the description is simple enough we just need to select the best vertex. Without the upper bounds $p_{kl}\le 1$ it is a transportation polytope, whose vertices are well-known (the bipartite graph formed by the nonzero entries must be acyclic), but with the upper bounds in place it seems to be quite a bit more complicated.  Perhaps the solution in the transportation case will provide some information?  It is at least a lower bound, and is exact if the row and column sums are at most 1.

Comment: In your thesis you seem to have the condition $\sum_{jk} p_{jk}=1$.  Do you have this condition here too?  If so, please add it.  In that case you have a transportation polytope and so the max and min of any linear function occurs at one of the (well-known) vertices of that polytope.

Comment: Thanks @BrendanMcKay for pointing out this confusion. Yes I have this condition here. I didn't write it down explicitly, because I thought "probability matrix" already covers it. Let me write it down.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I admittedly have no knowledge of transportation polytope and just looked it up. It does seem to be what I am looking for. Any chance you can point me to some literature on the "well-known vertices?" Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a description and algorithm in the accepted answer of this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75873/extreme-points-of-transportation-polytope . The referenced book of Brualdi is at https://books.google.com/books?id=xdP9d8S1BxQC .

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thank you very much, I'll make sure to read them carefully. One more point -- it seems that the references you mentioned mainly addressed "integer linear programming" questions. If we are doing this just for real numbers, would the solutions be easier to obtain?

Comment: You can just scale integer matrices to make the entries sum to 1, and real matrices are approximated arbitrarily closely by rational matrices.  So I think such things as description of the vertices remain the same.

Comment: Another observation is that this is an example of a minimum-cost flow problem. Optimal solutions can be characterised.  See http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/eric.thierry/Graphes2010/amaury-pouly.pdf for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37823/discussion-between-jerry-jiannan-lu-and-brendan-mckay).