# Weird transportation polytope

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, nonnegative-matrices

I'm looking to compute extremal points of a weird polytope. This polytope contains all matrices with positive entries $A \in \mathcal M_{n,m}\left(\mathbb R_+\right)$ such that:

- every row sum except the first one is prescribed to be $r_2,...r_n$, all positives values
- every column sum except the first one is prescribed to be $c_2,...c_m$, all positives values
- $a_{1,1} = 0$

It looks a lot like the traportation polytope from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75873/extreme-points-of-transportation-polytope) but with the aformentioned conditions added.

I'm looking to compute extremal points of this polytope, that is given a direction $d$,

$$v(d) = arg\min\limits_{x \in \mathcal C}\; \langle d,x\rangle.$$

Is there any litterature on this ? Could the [proposed method](https://mathoverflow.net/a/75905/143783) from the previously cited question be leveraged ?

---

**Proposition of a solution**

The optimisation problem we deal with is written as :

$$arg\min\limits\; d_{1,1}x_{1,1} + d_{1,2}x_{1,2} + \dots + d_{n,m}x_{n,m}.\\
\text{s.t:} \sum_{j=1}^m x_{i,j} = r_i \;\forall i \in \{2,...,n\}\\
\quad \sum_{i=1}^m x_{i,j} = c_j \;\forall j \in \{2,...,m\}\\
\quad x_{i,j}\ge0 \;\forall i,j \text{ and }x_{1,1}=0$$

The first thing to note is that, since all $x_{i,j}$ are positives, then for any ${i,j}$ such that $d_{i,j} \ge 0$, then $x_{i,j}^*$ should be 0.

We now need to deal with the negatives $d_{i,j}$. I propose the following recursive algorithm :
0. Set $x_{i,j}^* = 0$ for all $(i,j)$ such that $d_{i,j}$ = 0

1. Choose $i,j$ so that $d_{i,j}$ is the lowest one (biggest one in absolute value).
2. Assign $x_{i,j} = \min(r_i,c_j)$
3. Set now $d_{i,j} = 0$, $r_i = r_i - x_{i,j}$ and $c_i = c_i - x_{i,j}$
4. If any $d_{i,j}$ is still negative, go back to point 1.
5. Set $x_{i,1}^* += r_i$ and $x_{1,j}^* += c_j$ for the remainders.

What do you think about this algorithm ?

Would that produce the right optimum ? It's a fairly simple algorithm, does it have a name // is it known in the litterature or studied somewhere ?